# Starting a node with an specific HEAP amount in crate.yml

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory, crate

I'm editing the `Crate.yml` file in order to start a new node, my file is:

```
cluster.name: name
node.name: "name"
node.master: true
node.data: true
CRATE_HEAP_SIZE: 4g
```

When setting up `Crate` heap with 4g of RAM, it doesn't work when creating the default first node (when `Crate` starts) it creates the node with 1gb.

How should I define the heap size in the config file?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the config file /etc/default/crate and put this code

```
CRATE_HEAP_SIZE=4g
MAX_OPEN_FILES=65535
MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY=unlimited
```

edit /etc/security/limits.conf and put this params

```
crate            -       nofile          65535
crate            -       memlock         unlimited
```

finally activate this parameter in the configuration file config.yml

```
bootstrap.mlockall: true
```

Answer (score 4):

CRATE_HEAP_SIZE isn't a setting that you can set in the crate.yml file but instead it is an environment variable that you have to set beforehand.

e.g in a shell:

```
export CRATE_HEAP_SIZE=4g
bin/crate
```

If you're using a RPM based distro and installed crate using yum you can also change the values in the configuration file under /etc/sysconfig/crate